# Found stange url of my Magento site on Google search console

Tags: magento2, url

I am running a Magento 2 site, and try analysis the search or traffic of it with Google Search Console.

Recently, I found some strange url via Left-top menu "Performance" then middle sub-menu "Pages"(the second):
for example(abcd.com refers to my site):

http://abcd.com/http://prizedale.ru/5ixndt43jhlacroconcomd4  
http://abcd.com/http://xn--om4a.top/it723fq.htm 
http://abcd.com/http://xn--om4a.top/8yu7m6c.htm

They have quite some click count.

Are they a kind of attack? I have no idea why these urls exists and how&where they actually are.
I appreciate all suggestions and tips. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check via can running the **grep -r ‘{thirdparty}’** to find in files, if this url is not statically stored in your file.

Also check "search_query" table in magento DB if some anonymous link found.

Check if there is any unwanted script (spam script) loading on your site. Go for site Malware Scan oncep

Comment: Thank you for your tips.
I've double checked the sitemap and it seems normal.

In the examples that I provided, abcd.com is my site.
and the appended url is very suspicious, and the full url redirect finally to the appended part
(eg.http://xn--om4a.top/8yu7m6c.htm, which looks like spam site pages)

I am wondering how this kind of urls can appear in Google Search Console, and are there any problems need alerted

Comment: updated the answer please review once. Also add you site for Adobe security scan to find out the site health. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/systems/security/security-scan.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I DID found suspcious string via grep, in var/report, and is wondering how those codes are injected into my site:      var/report/700135992872:{"0":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused","1":"<pre>#1 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php:398]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->_connect() called at [vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php:460]\n#3 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `store_we...', array())

Comment: called at [vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Abstract.php:238]\n#4 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `store_we...', array()) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php:533]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->_query('SELECT `store_we...', array())

Comment: 。。。。[index.php:39]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/http:\/\/prizedale.ru\/1xpYdad26jhlacroconcomtp3","script_name":"\/index.php"}

Comment: Please search in you DB as well. Also what magento version you were using ? Please try to upgrade to the latest vesrion.

Comment: Thanks. After a more detailed investigation, I've confirmed that the scripts are normal. The only question now is:  when access http://my-magento-site.com/http://suspicious-site.com, it always finally redirect to http://suspicous-site.com。  How can I stop such redirect? Thanks again

Comment: @royce I am facing the same issue did you find a solution?